# Is there a way to get the expiration time of an access token in .net core

Tags: .net, oauth

So right now this is my code to add a github oauth to my web app.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => 
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;   
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddGitHub(Options =>
                {
                    Options.ClientId = "client";
                    Options.ClientSecret ="secret"; 
                    Options.Scope.Add("repo");
                    Options.SaveTokens = true;
                })
```

I can get the access token from the following code:

```
var token = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Is there a way to get the expiration time ?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I need to add a scope

```
.AddMicrosoftAccount(Options =>
                {
                    Options.ClientId = "client";
                    Options.ClientSecret ="secret"; 
                    Options.Scope.Add("repo");
                    Options.SaveTokens = true;
Options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                })
```

Then I can retrieve the refresh token by calling :

```
var token = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
```